# Print out or Traverse the Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, graph-theory, traversal

I want to print out the linked list that I've just made.
I've figured out how to print out the first and last element but can't think of a way to print the whole list.

I need to move from first element to next element 
and need a condition of stop at the end.

but I DO NOT IMPLEMENT iterator on this.
Just using pointer and nodes can I print the whole list?

```
int main ()
{ LinkedList name_list;
  name_list.TraPrinhead(name_list); }

void LinkedList::TraPrinHead(const LinkedList& p)
{ 
  cout << "The First Element of this List is : ";
  cout << header->next->elem; // print out the first element
  cout << endl;

  cout << "The Last Element of this List is : ";
  cout << tail->prev->elem; // print out the first element
  cout << endl;

  cout << "Now the whole list.......";
  cout << ??????????????????????
}






  class LinkedList {

  public: class Nodes { // Doubly Linked List Node
  public:
    Nodes(const string& e);
    void ToNodeValue(const string& e);
    string getElemValue() const;
    void printNodeValue();
  private:
     string elem;  // node element value
     Nodes* prev; // previous node in list
     Nodes* next; // next node in list
     // pointer that points to current node is this pointer

  public:
    void ConnectSingly(Nodes* a, Nodes* b); 
    void ConnectDoubly(Nodes* a, Nodes* b);

  friend class LinkedList; 
  };


  public:
    LinkedList(); 
    virtual ~LinkedList(); 
    bool empty() const; 
    const string& getFirst() const; 
    const string& getLast() const; 
    void addtoFront(const string& e); 
    void addtoBack(const string& e); 
    void TraPrinHead(const LinkedList& p); 
  private: 
     Nodes* header; 
     Nodes* tail;

  protected: 
    void InsertDoublyBefore(Nodes* d, const string& e); 
    void InsertDoublyAfter(Nodes* d, const string& e);

  friend class Nodes;
  };


       void LinkedList::InsertDoublyBefore(Nodes* d, const string& e) {

       if (header->next == tail)
         { // header->next->elem = e;
           Nodes* n = new Nodes;
        n->elem = e; 
            n->next = tail;
        n->prev = tail->prev;
            tail->prev->next = tail->prev = n; 
        header->next = n; 
       }
       else
       {
        Nodes* n = new Nodes; 
        n->elem = e;
        n->next = d;
        n->prev = d->prev;
        d->prev->next = d->prev = n; 
       }

       } 

       void LinkedList::InsertDoublyAfter(Nodes* d, const string& e) 
       {
          InsertDoublyBefore(d->next, e);
       }

       void LinkedList::addtoFront(const string& e)  { InsertDoublyBefore(header->next, e); }

       void LinkedList::addtoBack(const string& e) { InsertDoublyBefore(tail, e); }


       void LinkedList::Nodes::ConnectSingly(Nodes* a, Nodes* b)
       {
        a->next = b; // a's next pointer points to b
       }

       void LinkedList::Nodes::ConnectDoubly(Nodes* a, Nodes* b)
       {
        a->next = b; // a's next pointer points to b
        b->prev = a; // b's prev pointer points to a
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Node* p = myList.head;
while(p) {
  std::cout << p->elem << " ";;
  p = p->next;
}
```

It does as you would expect, continues to go to the next element until it is NULL(reaches end)
NULL is changed to 0 by the compiler, and 0==false

You should try looking at your lecture notes, since I already answered a question about this class for you.

Also, I believe that generally tail points to the last element, not one past it.
So printing the last element should be

```
cout << tail->elem; // print out the first element
```

**Unless your instructor defined otherwise.**

And clearly you are going to need to make 'getter' functions for most of these variables as they are declared to be private.

Comment: I get the infinite loop for this. Is there any way to stop at the end?

Comment: when p==tail, p->next==NULL. It will stop then.

It will stop when p is pointing to NULL.

Since, like I said, NULL==0==FALSE

Comment: I would double check your insert functions. And ensure that you keep tail->next as NULL, whenever you make add an element to the end(after tail)

Comment: Thanks, I posted my insert function.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994609/c-linked-list-printing-i-get-the-infinite-loop

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the linked list is that you can use one element to access the next element. So you just need to iterate through the list using a pointer.

```
Nodes* currentNodes = header->next; //pointer used to iterate through list; initially points at first element of list

while(currentNodes != tail) { //condition to stop
  cout << currentNodes->elem << endl; 
  currentNodes = currentNodes->next;
}
```

Comment: I can the infinite loop for this. Is there any way to stop at the end?